# ReSharper changes intellisense behaviour when initilizing objects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense, resharper-7.1, object-initialization

Let's assume I have a class

```
public class Dummy
{
    public int DummyInt { get; set; }
    public string DummyString { get; set; }
}
```

and somewhere in the code I have:

```
var dummy = new Dummy
{
```

In VS10, if I press now 'a' I will get a list of members: DummyInt,DummyString. But with ReSharper switched on nothing will be shown if I press 'a'. I must press 'd' to get both fields listed.

I went through ReSharper options, but I can't find it anywhere. Is it possible to switch that off?

R# 7.1

Comment: Why do you expect the letter 'a' to bring up class members that don't have the letter 'a' in them?  Maybe just use 'this.' if that's the behavior you want?

Comment: Thanks for response. Because I'm used to this. That's how original VS10 intellisense works. It's really good if you don't remember names of fields. You can press 'a' and a list of all members will be shown. 'this' won't help here.

Comment: I'll add that not the list of all fields will come up, but a list of all fields that you have not used yet. Extremely helpful when you do testing and need to create complicated dummy objects.

Comment: Yeah, realized that 'this.' does not do anything in that context.  The Resharper way to do this is to type Ctrl-Space or Ctrl-Shift-Space.

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Symbol.html and http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Smart.html

Comment: Please post Ctrl-Space as answer and I'll accept that! Thanks! That was so annoying!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27111/discussion-between-dpeden-and-mariusz-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resharper offers a couple different symbol completions.  The basic one is called [Symbol Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Symbol.html) and has a default key binding of Ctrl-Space.  The more intelligent one is called [Smart Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Smart.html) and has a default key binding of Ctrl-Shift-Space.